# php session strange behavior

Tags: php, session, routes

I have a PHP website with a custom page routing system.

A php script checks the requested uri and uses a `switch case` to determine which page needs to be loaded. Each page has its own `$page_id`.

Here's a simplified version.

```
$page_uri =  //code that extracts the relevent part of the uri

switch($page_uri){

case 'about':
  $page_id = 'about';
  break

case 'products':
  $page_id = 'products';
  break;

default:
  $page_id = '404';
  break;

}

include 'sessions.php'; //explanation about this after the code

include $page_id; //code that loads the page based on the $page_id
```

For one of the site's function, I need to know the `$page_id` of the previously visited page.

I am using sessions for this.

```
session_start();
$previous_page_id = $_SESSION['current_page_id'];
$_SESSION['current_page_id'] = $page_id;
```

I am therefore storing the previous `$page_id` which is stored in a session variable in the `$previous_page_id` variable before the session variable gets updated to the current `$page_id`.

The problem is that it doesn't work. The `$previous_page_id` is always equal to the default `$page_id` which is 404. I know the actual routing function works because the right page gets loaded and if I echo the value of the session right after storing it it's correct.

I've noticed that I can get the correct `$previous_page_id` if I put the following part before everything else.

```
session_start();
$previous_page_id = $_SESSION['current_page_id'];
```

What am I missing? Can you think of anything wrong with my code or logic? Is there some weird quirks I should be aware of when it comes to PHP sessions?

Thanks.

**Update**

It seems adding `session_start(); echo $_SESSION['current_page_id'];` at the top of the page makes the value stick. Otherwise by the time I get to transfering the session value to the `$previous_page_id` in sessions.php, the session value has changed to 404.

Can anyone make sense of that?

Comment: You could also put whole code.

Comment: Well, according to this manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php session_start() returns FALSE if session could not be started. Try to check it's result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming from a missing favicon.ico file which was triggering a 404 page load after each page load.

Comment: This is so bizarre but indeed caused all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the session_start(); at the beginning of the script, that way the session is started (and available) when you need it in your big switch statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think I need the session for the switch statement. The switch statement uses the $page_uri which is based on the requested URI. The switch statement's role is to define the $page_id.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add `.php` extension to your include (+ some smaller things). And remember that `session_start` must be called at beggining, before any use of it. So you need to call it on beggining or include sessions at beggining.

So it should look like:

```
session_start();

$page_uri =  //code that extracts the relevent part of the uri

switch($page_uri){

case 'about':
  $page_id = 'about';
  break;

case 'products':
  $page_id = 'products';
  break;

default:
  $page_id = '404';
  break;

}  

$previous_page_id = $_SESSION['current_page_id'];
$_SESSION['current_page_id'] = $page_id;

include $page_id . '.php'; //code that loads the page based on the $page_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$previous_page_id = $_SESSION['current_page_id'];
$_SESSION['current_page_id'] = $page_id;
```

I don't really get this. `$previous_page_id` and `$page_id` are equal.
You are setting them to be equal.

You should set it after the `switch` statement as follows:

```
$page_uri =  //code that extracts the relevent part of the uri

if (file_exists('sessions.php')) {
    include 'sessions.php';
} else {
    trigger_error("'sessions.php' not found", E_USER_ERROR);
}

switch($page_uri) {

case 'about':
  $page_id = 'about';
  break

case 'products':
  $page_id = 'products';
  break;

default:
  $page_id = '404';
  break;

}

if (isset($_SESSION['current_page_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['current_page_id'] = $page_id;
} else {
    trigger_error("'current_page_id' key not set", E_USER_ERROR);
}

if (isset($page_id)) {
    include $page_id;
} else {
    trigger_error("'page_id' not set", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

with `sessions.php` being:

```
$ss = session_start();
if (!$ss) { trigger_error("Session couldn't be started", E_USER_ERROR); 
if (isset($_SESSION['current_page_id'])) {
    $previous_page_id = $_SESSION['current_page_id'];
} else {
    trigger_error("'current_page_id' key not set", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: The idea is to give $previous_page_id the $page_id stored in the session. Since the code that sets the session to the current $page_id comes after, the session should have the previous' $page_id.

Comment: It seems you updated your answer to add code. Where do you set the session to $page_id. Wouldn't this always give me an empty $previous_page_id ?

Comment: @Enkay, not at all. `$previous_page_id` is set in `sessions.php` assuming `$_SESSION['current_page_id']` being always set. With my script you are setting `$page_id` inside the `switch` statement.

Comment: @Enkay, try my new updated code (both the main and `sessions.php`) and tell me what's the output.